# Check if javascript array contains not only empty values

Tags: javascript

I want check if array contains not only empty strings or nulls.

```
arr = ['','','','','',''];
```

What is the most elegant way without loops to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This is my best solution for now because array.filter have worse browser support.

```
if(!arr.join('')){/*your code*/}
```